# laravel validation with database condition using validation function

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, validation

laravel validation with database condition using validation function

I have a laravel controller PostContoller and Post model
I want to use name condition with database table

My table name posts and make name unique and where post_type = example_post_type_name

Please help?

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title'     => 'required|max:191',
        'name'      => 'required|max:191|unique:lcf_posts',
        'status'    => 'required|max:191',
    ]);
```

Comment: not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: i submit a form data this is save function in the controller and i want a , check the condition before where post_type=post and name is unique

Comment: is that clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Add Additional Where Clauses:](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique)

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'title'     => 'required|max:191',
    'name'      => [
             'required',
             'max:191',
             Rule::unique('lcf_posts')->where(function ($query) {
                return $query->where('post_type ','example_post_type_name');
             })],
    'status'    => 'required|max:191',
]);
```

Comment: how to i use model name Post instead of table name?